# Low quality iTunes API preview url

Tags: api, itunes, libspotify, itunes-api

I'm working with iTunes API to offer preview playbacks in my app. So I have links like this:

```
http://a1780.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/039/Music3/v4/b8/b3/7a/b8b37a93-2154-34da-74fc-8e8a316979a8/mzaf_7991652075174454658.plus.aac.p.m4a
```

It works almost perfectly! I was wondering if there is some workaround to get a low quality version of this preview (by modifying url, for example, as we can do with artworkUrl to get larger or smaller cover images).

Even it's already very small size (1MB), users will usually listen to several songs, so I'm trying to save their bandwidth (if it's not on WiFi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think 1 MB is not small. These 256 kbps m4a files are much too large. I would encode such to ~48 kbps (resulting in ~110 KB files).

But I would be happy with any other option, just smaller than atm.